# InArray doesn't recognize this.value but recognize normal numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#something').on("keydown", function(e) {
        var x = [0,6,7,3,2];
        var y = this.value;
        var z = $.inArray(y, x);
        if(z > -1){
            alert('EXISTS');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' id='something'>
```

My code here doesn't work when i `y = this.value` but if i replaced it with `y = 0;` it works as intended, Why won't it work with `y = this.value`

Comment: $(this).val() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your array is full of integers, yet `this.value` is a string. You need to convert the types to match.

Also note that using `keyup` or `input` makes far more sense than `keydown`, otherwise the previous value will only be evaluated on the next event occurrence. Try this:

```js
$('#something').on("input", function(e) {
  var x = [0, 6, 7, 3, 2];
  var y = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  var z = $.inArray(y, x);
  if (z > -1) {
    console.log('EXISTS');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' id='something'>
```

Comment: Perfectly working, But if it gets the value as string, Why if i wrote `if($.isNumeric(this.value)){alert('NUMBER');}` it would work normally?

Comment: That's because it checks if the value *can* be converted to a number, it doesn't actually convert it